# How to disconnect this loop relation

Tags: ms-access, database-design, relational-database

I have a database, contains these tables. but the relation is loop and it causes problem when creating a form.

We have many classes, each class may have more than one QUIZS, but not all classes have the same QUIZS, they are different, and for each QUIZ students have mark.

The way I designed the databbase is quizs are related to each class one-to-many and quizs are related to student as many-to-many relationship, an inner table ( Quiz-degree) in between.
The issue is it becomes a loop design becaus quis is also related to the ckass table.

I tried to think of a better design but could not find a one.

Appreciate if someone has a better design.
[image]

Comment: Could you describe what you want to achieve. For example, there are students and assigned to different classes and they will have quiz and then they will get a degree with mark.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no referential integrity in your design except for foreign keys referencing the Class table. You should probably fix that. Apart from that there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your design.

As far as we can tell from the diagram there is no circular dependency in the sense that ER modellers normally understand it because A) Not all the tables have foreign keys, B) If all tables did have foreign keys then they would not form a directed loop anyway.

The only question here is what problem you have when using forms. You didn't explain the problem but in any case it's usually very unwise to structure your database design around the needs of the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. my issues with this design is I am not able to create a from per student to display all QUIZes for that students and enter the degree for each one.

I manged to create a one with a sub form for QUIZes but fields are not updatable.

I think the issues is the loop design, that is why I was seeking another pattern.